How to pin widget dynamically in flutter using CustomScrollView and Silvers
I want to replicate the category tabbar to automatically show the current category in a listview. The tabbar should be hidden until the headerWidget is fully hidden. Example:

I tried using opacity and some animation but it just feels clunky.
Minimal example code:
  ...
  late TabController tabController;
  late AutoScrollController autoScrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    autoScrollController = AutoScrollController();
    tabController = TabController(length: 1, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: VerticalScrollableTabView(
        autoScrollController: autoScrollController,
        scrollbarThumbVisibility: false,
        tabController: tabController,
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 250.0,
            flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text("SliverAppBar"),
              titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
              collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
            ),
            bottom: TabBar(
              controller: tabController,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'Highlights'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
        listItemData: [...List<String>.generate(100, (counter) => "Item $counter")],
        eachItemChild: (aaa, int index) {
          return Text("Test");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

